# PuTTY fatal error: "No supported authentication methods available"

Tags: putty, fatal-error

PuTTY fatal error:

```
No supported authentication methods available
```

When I tried to login into the production server, I am getting above error. Could anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Are you using any private-public key authentication?

Comment: I have just downloaded putty exe and then tried to login into production server by giving host name and port number. I am not using any private-public key authentication.

Answer (score 16):

In my case, I updated the Putty application to the latest and issue was solved.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! I tried so many different things, thinking I was just doing something wrong. But I updated from 0.74 to 0.78 and suddenly it worked! Without changing any settings for the connection. Cheers

Comment: I was having the same error. I updated to version 0.78 and worked for me too. Thank you!

Comment: Same here, thank you!

Comment: I wish I could upvote 20 times...  Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

Edit file

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Set PasswordAuthentication yes
[image]

Then restart server

```
sudo service ssh restart
sudo service sshd restart
```

Comment: `systemctl  restart  sshd.service ;   ## for newer releases`

Answer (score 7):

It worked for me after I did the following steps :

1- Download Puttygen (https://www.puttygen.com/download-putty)

2- Open PUttyGen and then Load the private key from :

C:\Users[username]\Chapter6.vagrant\machines\default\virtualbox

3- save the new private key with a new name.

4- Open Putty, go to Connection > SSH > Auth > and add the new private key

5- Connect now using 127.0.0.1 and 2222

Answer (score 1):

I think your private key file format is not compatible with putty for putty uses its' native format instead.

Detail:http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter10.html#errors-no-auth

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cloud service and trying to connect server using ssh then Don't login the user name as ec2-user, the default user name is ubuntu forubuntu server.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved via Puttygen

I was on a windows system and it doesnt support direct shell access like linux or macOS.

1. Download Puttygen.
2. Load the .pem key to puttygen
3. Save as Private key
4. Use this key to login to ec2 instance

P.S : Also if the SSH ask for login/username - enter ubuntu or admin

Answer (score 1):

This error can also be seen if you haven’t selected the .ppk file for the session in Putty: Connection > SSH > Auth

You’re done if you’ve employed PuttyGen to generate the keys. Else import the private key to your .ppk file as others have instructed.

Note on Linux as opposed to Windows, puttygen is accessed only via the command line. Here’s some resources for that:

[https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.76/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.76/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey)

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/puttygen.1.html

https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/putty/linux/puttygen

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have access to the server (maybe an open shell?) Check  `/var/log/messages` for more details. This could have something to do with your PAM configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change folder permissions? i met this question in this week, so i find the error that is cause to me change the folder(name is ec2-user) permission.

Answer (score 0):

1.Edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.
2.Change PasswordAuthentication and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to yes.
3a. Restart ssh /etc/init.d/ssh restart. 
OR 
3b. better you use service sshd restart

Answer (score 0):

If you've saved your public key on an external drive and it's not connected, putty will throw this error when connecting to your remote server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Puttygen
2. Load the .pem key to puttygen
3. convert .pem file to .ppk
4. Save as Private key
5. Install/Open Putty >> puTTY Configuration >> Auth >> Browse >> path to .ppk file

Use this key to login to ec2 instance (check that IP of remote server is allowed in security group config of EC2 instance)

Username

The usual user names are ec2-user, ubuntu, centos, root, or admin

Answer (score 0):

If that server is in the cloud like AWS, the rookie mistake I did was not realizing that a new Public IPv4 DNS gets used when the instance was off for some time. So, check the new DNS

Answer (score 0):

Today I faced the same problem. So in putty you have to use "user name" of your EC2 instance
**to get your "user name" of your EC2 instance**

- Select EC2 instance
- select Connect
  [image]

Now go to **putty** use  **ec2_name@public address**

***To see your public address***

- select EC2
- under details you will be able to see your public address.

Now try loading your "ppk" file you will be able to log in.

Answer (score 0):

For Digital Ocean, we should enable password authentication first.

The complete instruction is here: https://docs.digitalocean.com/support/i-lost-the-ssh-key-for-my-droplet/#enable-password-authentication

> Log in to the Droplet via the Recovery Console
> Even though you have a root password for the Droplet, if you try to log in via SSH using that password immediately, you’ll receive a Permission denied (publickey) error. This is because password authentication is still disabled on the Droplet. To fix this, you need to log in via the Recovery Console and update its SSH configuration.
>
> There are detailed instructions on how to connect to Droplets with the
> Recovery Console for a more explicit walkthrough, but here’s a brief
> summary:
>
> On the Droplet’s detail page, in the same Access tab, click the Launch
> Console button.
>
> At the login prompt, enter root as the username.
>
> At the subsequent password prompt, enter the root password you were
> sent via email. Most distributions prompt you to enter the password
> twice, but some (like Fedora 27) do not.
>
> Enter a new root password to replace the one that was emailed to you,
> then enter that same new password again.
>
> You will now be logged in as root in the Recovery Console, which gives
> you access to the Droplet’s SSH configuration.
>
> Enable Password Authentication To enable password authentication on
> your Droplet, you need to modify a line in its SSH config file, which
> is /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
>
> Open /etc/ssh/sshd_config using your preferred text editor, like nano
> or vim. Find the line that reads PasswordAuthentication no line and
> change it to PasswordAuthentication yes, then save and exit the file.
>
> Because the SSH daemon only reads its configuration files when it’s
> first starting, you need to restart it for these changes to take
> effect. The command to do this depends on your operating system:
>
> Operating System  SSH Restart Command 
> Ubuntu 14.x   service ssh restart
> Ubuntu 15.4 and up    systemctl restart ssh 
> Debian    systemctl restart ssh
> CentOS 6  service sshd restart 
> CentOS 7  systemctl restart sshd
> Fedora    systemctl restart sshd\

Answer (score 0):

***Putty Authentication Issue***

You are using public private key authentication here, you needs generate **private key** using putty key generator.

This might happen because you are **passing wrong ppk file** (like passing public key file instead if private key)
You are using public private key authentication here, you needs generate **private key** using putty key generator.

Once private key ppk file generated, you can **upload private key file** into
**Putty -> Connection -> SSH -> Auth**

Answer (score 0):

Please use below steps to fix this.

You are using wrong or selecting worng .pem file in puttygen. While selecting the .pem file use all files

[Select all files and then select your .pem file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zospb.png)
Conclusion, Please check your .pem file and retry again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was using frequently **TortoiseGit**. For some unknown reason i got the error one morning. I just checked the keys from here: [image: putty authentication agent]

[image: Pageant Key List]

There was no key while i checked. Then i just added the private key(clicking "Add key"-> select private key .ppk file). Now all ok.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i am using ubuntu 22, the RSA key authentication is removed.

[see reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409105/ubuntu-22-04-ssh-the-rsa-key-isnt-working-since-upgrading-from-20-04)
so by using ECDSA key the problem was solved.

puttygen screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows try **enabling** TIS and interactive keyboard under 'auth'

[https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter10.html#:~:text=10.10%20'No%20supported%20authentication%20methods,in%20which%20case%20section%204.20](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter10.html#:%7E:text=10.10%20%27No%20supported%20authentication%20methods,in%20which%20case%20section%204.20).

[image]